# MySQL, add column 'FullNameReverseOrder' using data from fullname column and changing (FName, LName) to (LName, FName)

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to add a new column called FullNameReverseOrder to a table called NameTable where the info for the FullName is in FirstName LastName order and the FullNameReverseOrder will hold the LastName FirstName order.

this is a table you can use:

```
create table NameTable (ID int, FullName varchar(100), age int, primary key(ID));
insert into NameTable (ID, FullName, age) values(1, 'ben thompson', 23);

add the new column called FullNameReverseOrder:
alter table NameTable add column FullNameReverseOrder varchar(100) ...no idea what to do here... after FullName;
```

Comment: The first two statements refer to a table called `NameTable`, the last one refers to a table called `FullName`.  Typo?

Comment: I'd suggest having first name and last name in separate fields, because you may face problems extracting them from full name, e.g. `Nabeel El Habbash` and `Erich Maria Remarque` would be parsed differently. Then, you might have `FullName` and `FullNameReverseOrder` as GENERATED columns.

Comment: that's a different problem.. I want to know and learn to answer the question I asked above. thanks

Comment: OK, where do FirstName and LastName come from in your example? Since you have FullName only, first you have to do is to get FirstName and LastName from FullName. So it brings us back to my previous comment.

Comment: You want to add column and directly populate it based on values from a different column in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points to consider.

- Do not store age, it will change every year and the table needs update, use date of birth instead.
- Use separated column per FirstName , LastName and MiddleName if there is one.

As per the question

Consider the following data examples which consider the `FullName` column has maximum three words separated by space

```
create table NameTable (
  ID int, 
  FullName varchar(100), 
  age int, 
  primary key(ID) );

insert into NameTable (ID, FullName, age) values
  (1, 'ben thompson', 23),
  (2, 'Martin Luther King', 23);
```

Query ,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(FullName), ' ', -1) LastName,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(FullName), ' ', 1) FirstName,
       SUBSTR(FullName, LOCATE(' ',FullName) + 1,  (CHAR_LENGTH(FullName) - LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(FullName)) - LOCATE(' ',FullName)))  AS MiddleName   
FROM NameTable;
```

Result,

```
LastName    FirstName   MiddleName
Thompson      Ben   
King          Martin      Luther
```

First change the table structure by altering , I always suggest proper locinkg the table if there is a large number of transactions

```
SET autocommit=0; 
LOCK TABLES NameTable WRITE; 
alter table NameTable add column FullNameReverseOrder varchar(100) after FullName;
COMMIT; 
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

To update the new added column LastName , MiddleName, FirstName use,

```
update NameTable
set FullNameReverseOrder = concat_ws(' ' ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(FullName), ' ', -1),
                                  SUBSTR(FullName, LOCATE(' ',FullName)+1,  (CHAR_LENGTH(FullName) - LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(FullName)) - LOCATE(' ',FullName))),
                                  SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(FullName), ' ', 1) );
```

Select ,

```
select * 
from NameTable;
```

Result

```
ID  FullName             FullNameReverseOrder      age
1   ben thompson          thompson  ben            23
2   Martin Luther King    King Luther Martin       23
```

Now if you want the process automatic, consider creating a trigger .

```
CREATE TRIGGER FullNameReverseOrderUpdate BEFORE INSERT ON NameTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET new.FullNameReverseOrder = (concat_ws(' ' ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(new.FullName), ' ', -1),
                                  SUBSTR(new.FullName, LOCATE(' ',new.FullName)+1,  (CHAR_LENGTH(new.FullName) - LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(new.FullName)) - LOCATE(' ',new.FullName))),SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(new.FullName), ' ', 1) ));
END;
```

Insert test value

```
insert into NameTable (ID, FullName, age) values
  (3, 'Arthur  Thompson', 23);

select * from NameTable;
```

Result

```
ID  FullName             FullNameReverseOrder     age
1   ben thompson           thompson  ben           23
2   Martin Luther King     King Luther Martin      23
3   Arthur  Thompson       Thompson  Arthur        23
```

[Se examplee](https://dbfiddle.uk/NjHmyJNw)

Answer (score 0):

After adding your new column `FullNameReverseOrder` you could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to split on the first space to get the first name (this is an assumption that first names don't contain spaces).

```
<first name> = SUBSTRING_INDEX(FullName, ' ', 1)
```

The last name is then the remainder of the `FullName` string after the first name (and space).

```
<last name> = SUBSTRING(FullName, LENGTH(<first name>) + 1)
```

You can use `CONCAT` to join the parts again.  Putting it all together:

```
UPDATE NameTable SET FullNameReverseOrder = CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(FullName, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(FullName, ' ', 1)) + 1),
  ' ',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(FullName, ' ', 1)
);
```